# When do we use "distemper" instead of "disorder"?

Tags: word-usage

Please help me. I have searched all the famous dictionaries but still I can't understand when should I use it as a noun(*except for political matters*) and when to use it as a verb, both in place of disorder(*not for painting or a disease*).

Is this a common word to use nowadays except for a disease or painting?

Comment: I think you mean "distemperate" or even rarer "distemperature".

Comment: Hi, I don't think so :) I was looking for distemper. Oxford dictionary has no defenition for "distemperate" and "distemperature".

Comment: I have a hunch that many people don't use *distemper* for anything else beside the disease or that kind of paintings, and when they do it could cause confusions. I found an interesting discussion that mentioned cat's distemper here: http://www.thecatsite.com/t/93735/a-distemper-shot-for-a-bad-temper

Comment: @DamkerngT. Thank you very much. I agree with you. I searched "The Telegraph"s website and I must say 99 per cent of results was either about disease or painting.

Comment: That would be an understatement! In general, I doubt that even 0.001% of all instances in recent decades would be for OED's definition 5: *Derangement, disturbance, or disorder (esp. in a state or body politic)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I am just not well-read enough, but at least in spoken English (I am a native of the US) I am only aware of distemper being used to refer to the disease affecting dogs.

Answer (score 0):

Disorder is used to describe an illness or condition that affects function(s) of the mind or body (e.g. Anxiety Disorder), whereas distemper refers to a canine illness (e.g. Canine Distemper).